# Tightening sequence for water pump bolts (Peugeot 406 1.8 16V)

Tags: water-pump, bolts, peugeot-406

I'm curious about the tightening sequence of this water pump. The manual says nothing about it. I have included 2 pictures and assigned numbers to the bolts. What sequence do you recommend for this type of water pump?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no tightening sequence listed in the service manual, I would just use a star pattern.
Probably 1,3,5,2,4.

Comment: Can I use a pattern like cylinder head bolts? Starting from the middle and going towards the ends.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian which order would you suggest that is like a cylinder head?  A cylinder head is not circular like this water pump.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I was thinking about the common cylinder head tightening sequence for most cars. What is your suggestion for the above water pump?

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian. I would do it very similar to what this answer says.  I upvoted this answer.

Comment: @HandyHowie  - So, you also agree with the star pattern. Ok, I'll go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Tighten evenly, and to the torque specified but you have that from the manual.

Comment: Unfortunately, the manual says nothing. It just simply says install or remove the water pump! In some Peugeot forums, they say tightening torque is 10 nm but others say 15 nm.

Comment: Some manuals have a page of bolt sizes and associated torques. The manuals I have bought - from the dealer / manufacturer do have the torques listed and they include Peugeot, Citroen and Talbot as well as Chrysler, Rolls Royce, Bentley, Jaguar, Hillman, Landrover to name but a few. Don’t have them all to hand but I do know Peugeot does list torques as I used to work on them.

Comment: A google search can work wonders: https://static.piecesauto.com/images//medias/docs/0050/nt03012en0914.pdf Now you **do** have a torque wrench and know how to use it I presume...

Comment: Yes, Peugeot definitely lists torque specs and I have the specs for most bolts. That's why I wonder why they haven't listed water pump torque specs for my specific engine. I have a torque wrench but I think I have to use my hands because there is not enough room around some bolts.